# Handle invalid subdomains without a wildcard SSL certificate

Tags: nginx, domain-name-system

I want to be able to handle requests for invalid subdomains like `https://wwwe.mydomain.com` in order to show a meaningful error message (example- https://sdfsdf.github.com). My nginx config does this currently but only for non-http**s** addresses.

For `https://` locations the browser throws an error because I don't have the subdomain on my SSL certificate. I have certificate from letsencrypt which doesnt allow wildcards and I can't afford one from other providers.

Is there any way around this?

Comment: No, there isn't.

Comment: I was hoping a DNS redirect with cname record might help. But looks like a low tech solution is on the way .. https://letsencrypt.org/2017/07/06/wildcard-certificates-coming-jan-2018.html

Comment: A CNAME is not a redirect. It's more like an alias.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately there's no way around requiring a wildcard certificate for meeting your use case.  It looks like LetsEncrypt will be offering wildcard certs starting in January 2018 though.

If this is for a non-profit or a startup, it looks like free wildcard certs may be available from Symantec:

https://www.freessl.com/freessl/good-karma/

Comment: The Symantec CA is [about to be phased out by Chrome though](https://security.googleblog.com/2017/09/chromes-plan-to-distrust-symantec.html). Usually the other browser vendors follow that path sooner or later.